# MVC 4 Regular Expression in View Model - date

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am creating MVC application and in my ViewModel I am trying to validate if input is of form DD/MM/YYYY and I do this like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+(/)+[0-9]+(/)+[1-9]$", ErrorMessage = "Input date has to be of form DD/MM/YYYY")]
```

How do I do it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think using regular expressions is the best way to do this, you can use DataType for validate and DisplayFormat for get your date formated.

your code be like something like that:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime dateValidation {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your date as a string in the model then use the following

```
[RegularExpression(@"(((0|1)[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/((19|20)\d\d))$"]
```

Comment: You only validates 1900+ dates the OP is asking for yyyy format